# SKProductRequestDelegate Crashing when leaving view

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have implemented an IAP Scene `OptionsPage: SKScene` where users can purchase "Remove Ads" and in game currency etc. But if I go from `MenuScene: SKScene` to the `OptionsPage: SKScene` and back to the menu quickly it crashes with `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x216d0716)` and the only thing in the log down the bottom is (lldb).

I am calling `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)` in `willMoveFromView()`.

In my `didMoveToView` I call the `setIAP()` function (shown below).

After constantly bashing my head against a table (first time dealing with IAP) , I think that it is happening because I've set `request.delegate = self` and so when I enter the scene `request.start()` runs but because I quickly leave the scene `request.delegate = self` is no longer valid.

I thought removing the transaction observer would deal with this in `willMoveFromView`. How can I get around this problem?

Here is how I am calling the purchase in `touchesBegan()`

```
if removeAds.containsPoint(location) {
                for product in list {
                    let prodID = product.productIdentifier
                    if (prodID == "removeAds") {
                        p = product
                        buyProduct()
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is how the IAP section looks in

```
// MARK: In App Purchases

func setIAP() {
    // Set IAPS
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        print("IAP is enabled, loading")
        let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "removeAds, 10000coins")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
    }
}

var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    let myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        print("Product added: \(product.productIdentifier), \(product.localizedTitle), \(product.localizedDescription), \(product.price)")

        list.append(product)
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {

    print("transactions restored")
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "removeAds":
            defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "removeAdsPurchased")

        default:
            print("IAP not setup")
        }
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Thank You", message: "Thankyou for your purchase.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased, .Restored:
            print(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "removeAds":

                defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "removeAdsPurchased")

            case "10000Coins":

                defaults.setInteger(bank + 10000, forKey: "bankValue")
                bank = defaults.integerForKey("bankValue")

            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;

        case .Failed:
            print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;

        default:
            print("default")
            break;
        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction) {
    print("Transaction finished")
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("Transaction removed")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this, seeing as there was no feedback, was very tedious but as follows:

Rather than have two scenes I combined the Menu and options scene so that when the options button is tapped, it runs an action to slide the menu nodes off the screen and options onto the screen. This way the `request.delegate = self` doesn't change therefore avoiding the crash. Then the only issue was if I launch the app and press the play button quickly to move to the game scene before the `request.start` finishes it would get the same crash. So I created a loading splash screen to run for 2 seconds in the menu scenes `didMoveToView` this way it had plenty of time to get all the data before allowing interaction.

I would love to hear of a more simple solution but with the little experience I have this is what I came up with.